# Using map_coordinates to upscale an image

Tags: image-processing

I am tasked with creating a low-resolution version of an image with the same shape by reducing the image's shape randomly (to lose data) and expanding it back. However, I cannot use any of the 'resize' methods such as in scikit/opencv.. and only allowed to use scipy.ndimage.zoom and map_coordinates.

I've managed to do the following: (im is an grayscale image)

```
factor = np.random.uniform(0.25, 1)
zoomed_im = ndimage.zoom(im, zoom)
height_range = np.arange(0, im.shape[0])
width_range = np.arange(0, im.shape[1])
col, row = np.meshgrid(width_range, height_range)
zoom_out = map_coordinates(input=zoomed_in, coordinates=[row, col])
```

however I get the same zoomed in image with the rest of the pixels added as black. I understand this is due to the default parameters of map_coordinates being :

```
mode='constant'
cval = 0.0
```

How can I enlarge the image back using interpolation to the same original shape?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a different step size in np.arange():

```
factor = np.random.uniform(0.25, 1)
zoomed_im = ndimage.zoom(im, factor)
height_range = np.arange(0, im.shape[0]*factor, step=factor)
width_range = np.arange(0, im.shape[1]*factor, step=factor)
```